# Mongoose calls hangs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I haven't worked on my PC for few days.

Suddenly all the calls to mongo via mongoose hangs up, the callbacks are not called.

I checked that my call to .connect works, and that the connection state is 1 (connected).

I also made sure mongo service is running on localhost and the appropriate port 27017, and I can use the mongo console and query the db manually.

I also scanned the Internet for solutions but all I found was 'check that you're actually connected', and I verified that already.

Mongoose version 2.15.0, mongo version 2.4.9 and node js version is 4.4.2.

Comment: Are you using promises or regular callbacks?

Comment: I would recommend to create new file in new folder then "*npm install mongoose*", in the file require mongoose, copy/paste one of your existing schema/model definition and try `SomeModel.find({},function(){...});`

Comment: OK I realized that when the schema sits in the node modules of the module then it works. What I've done before is moving it one level up in the hierarchy to the node modules folder of all my other services  (since I'd like to share schemas with all my micro services). In the last manner it does not work. But when I move it one level down inside the module itself then the call is working...

Comment: But it's still not good because I'd like it to stay in the global node modules hierarchy so it will be available to all the micro services...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it.

Problem was duplicate references to the mongoose module.

I had a mongoose reference locally (which was connected), but my schema was present higher in the node_modules hierarchy, and it have used another mongoose instance which had no connection.

Once I removed the duplicate mongoose modules (npm uninstall mongoose one of them) it worked.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. This took me forever to figure out.

For the sake of Google, my issue cropped up when I was trying to set up a CLI using Docker. I had included another library in my CLI container and it was including Mongoose. This was causing the conflict.

Comment: ME TOO. This was a problem that's extremely difficult to discover. In my case I used a private NPM library where I'm also using Mongoose. I had the model in the library, but I made the Mongo connection from my app. There were apparently two Mongoose instances as a result, and it failed silently, costing me 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions didn't work for me so I fixed with following solution.

I had same issue where my db calls used to hang with no invocation to my callbacks or the promise resolution.

The problem was I used "***createConnection()***" to establish the connection with the db. But it didn't work perfectly.

Instead using "***connect()***" and "***connection***" imports worked.

Here is the sample code. Hope this helps.

```
import { connect, connection } from "mongoose";

const mongoUri = `mongodb://${my_mongo_host_&_port}`;
connect(mongoUri, {}); //to connect to my standalone db


//"connection" to listen to events
connection.on("connected", () => {
 console.log("MongoDB connection established!", mongoUri);
});
```

I am working with "**mongoose": "^6.6.1**".